# ConEmu исполнение *.js файлов

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-7

Смотрю уроки, там преподаватель использует ConEmu, и вот к примеру пишет такой код:

```
js script.js
```

И после нажатия на энтер, обрабатывает файл script.js, и выводит значения...

А у меня пишет "js не является внутренней или внешней командой"...

Читал читал, что то начитал про wscript.exe - что он отвечает за исполнение файлов, но так и не понял до конца...

Вопрос: Как добиться того, что бы можно было исполнять *.js файлы в ConEmu?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20220539/1405560

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вызывайте в папке с вашим скриптом:

```
\путь_до_wscript\wscript.exe script.js
```

Или добавьте путь до **wscript.exe** в PATH (переменные среды). Тогда можно будет в директории со скриптом делать так:

```
wscript.exe script.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Установи [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), там будет тебе консоль в которой напишешь node, нажмёшь Enter и потом уже сможешь писать свой js. А будет желание почитай документацию к node.js, там описано как запускать код из файла (например из того же файла script.js). Успехов!